# Create node script to generate JavaScript file that exports a dynamic object

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I would like to create a node script that generates a JavaScript file that exports a dynamic object.

I have looked at `babel-plugin-preval` and `babel-plugin-codegen`, but I can't pass a dynamic object into their API.

Here is what I'm looking for.

```
// package.json

"scripts": {
   "generate": "node my-script.js"
}
```

```
// my-script.js

const obj = {
   a: 1
}

// Create new-file.js that exports this obj
```

```
// generate new-file.js

export default {
    a: 1
}
```

Comment: That object from `my-script` doesn't appear to be dynamically generated? Also, I don't see why you could do that dynamic generation inside a `codegen` macro

Comment: Ya that object is for simplicity sake. Imagine the value presented is what it resolves into. When I use codegen`module.exports = ${obj}` I receive an error `{ SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: You'll need to produce valid JS code. Try logging `String(obj)` to see that it doesn't. Use something like `module.exports = 'export default '+JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: @Bergi Ok that's looking good. The JSON.stringify is wrapping all keys in quotes. Is there a way to do this so that doesn't happen?

Also, when I did the `module.exports = 'export default + ${JSON.stringify(obj)'`, I got the following error: `{ SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (2:21)` pointing at the 'e' in 'export'. I hacked around this by passing this to code to codegen and then adding the export default to the start of the file: `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(obj)};`